# How can I prove $q+1 \vert q^n + 1 \iff \ n$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $q\geq 2$. Then $q+1 \vert q^n + 1 \iff \ n$ is odd

How can I prove it?

I don't know how to start.

Any hints?.

Comment: Hint:  factor the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2n+1}+1$ noting that $f(-1)=0$.

Comment: @lulu good hint